# MVC Required Validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5.1

My model is :-

```
public class instrument
{
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Instrument Id")]
    public String InstrumentId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }      

    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer"),Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public List<string> manufacturer
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 .....
 .....
}
```

my view has these

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.manufacturer[0], htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.manufacturer[0], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.manufacturer[0], "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.manufacturer[1], htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.manufacturer[1], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.manufacturer[1], "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I submit form to my controller (with out putting any value in both these textboxes) The List manufacturer contains two empty strings. I want to validate these. as Model.IsValid always comes true because manufacturer has two empty strings.

Comment: What is the actual validation you want (`[Required]` does not work on a collection) - do you want to ensure every item in the collection is not null/empty string?

Comment: yes. I want to do that.

Comment: Then property `manufacturer` needs to be List<Manufacturer>` where `Manufacturer` is a class containing a property (say) `string Name` that is decorated with the `[Required]` attribute. But you should not be generating your view that way. Instead, use a `for` loop

Comment: ok. but i thought that these are simple of strings which are manufacturer names.as i was saving them in documentDB.Thanks any ways.

Comment: `[Required]` validates that the property your applying it to is not `null`. Since your `List<string>` can never be `null` then it always passes validation

Comment: Yes I understood the reason.But I was trying to bypass custom validation and want to see that if MVC has any solution for that rather than overdoing the things. I changed it as the way you suggested. But since i was using Automapper so now that is creating problem in mapping . :). I will look for that. Thank you so much Sir

Answer (score 0):

You can use required attributes to validate you model  like  `[Display(Name = "Id")]` for displaying Id for all properties in model

Answer (score 0):

The manufacturer could have his own class in the model:

```
public class Instrument
{
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Instrument Id")]
    public String InstrumentId { get; set; }      

    public List<Manufacturer> Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Manufacturer[0].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```